# mysql multiple record set from group by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE payments(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fromid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  toid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  amount INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO payments
(fromid, toid, amount)
VALUES
(1, 2, 10),
(1, 3, 20),
(1, 4, 30),
(2, 4, 10),
(4, 3, 20);
```

and this query:

```
SELECT `toid` AS `userid`, 
SUM(`grouped_amount`) AS `balance` 
FROM (
   SELECT `t2`.`toid`, SUM(`t2`.`amount`) AS `grouped_amount`
   FROM (
       SELECT * FROM `payments`
   ) AS `t2` GROUP BY `toid` UNION 
   SELECT `t1`.`fromid`, -SUM(`t1`.`amount`)
   FROM (
       SELECT * FROM `payments`
   )AS `t1` GROUP BY `fromid`)
AS `t` GROUP BY `toid`;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9980e3/3) is a sqlfiddle with my table, and working result, BUT I'm worried about performance. There are 2 totally identical subqueries. I want to make this in 1 query, is it possible?

So problem is: based on my table, calculate balance of users after all payments.

That's how I'm doing it now: group and sum all payments FROM every user and mark result with - sign. And group and sum all payments TO every user and mark it with + sign. Union this results, and after that sum and group again.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I believe this is a graph walking problem and requires iteration.  MySQL is not suited to these sorts of tasks, because it supports neither hierarchical queries nor recursion, although you could write a stored procedure to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost fine, you're just nesting more than necessary. Write it like this:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(mysum) AS Balance
FROM (

    SELECT
    toid as userid, SUM(amount) as mysum
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY toid

UNION ALL

    SELECT
    fromid, SUM(amount) * -1
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY fromid

) sq
GROUP BY userid;
```

There's little room for improvement and to meet your requirements you can hardly write it another way. I made it `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. Difference is, that `UNION` without `ALL` implies a `DISTINCT` which you don't need / want.

Comment: oh, yeah. I don't really know why I have subquery in this place.

Comment: But what about this double subquery? Nothing can be done?

Or I don't need this?

Comment: You can not write it another way, since they are actually not identical. Two different columns you're selecting and grouping by. Don't worry too much, I'm sure it will run quite smooth. If not, consider adding indexes. Maybe 2 combined indexes on (toid, amount) and (fromid, amount).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reduce the overhead consequently:

```
SELECT `userid` , SUM(`amount`) AS `balance` 
FROM (
   SELECT `toid` AS `userid`, `amount`
   FROM `payments`
   UNION ALL
   SELECT `fromid` AS `userid`, -1*`amount` AS `amount`
   FROM `payments`
) AS `t` 
GROUP BY `userid`;
```

A solution to remove the UNION operation is to change 'a bit' your model. You would have to have only one `userid` field, and an additional `payment_type` column with values `from` or `to`. This way the select would look like this:

```
SELECT `userid` , SUM(IF(`payment_type` = `from`,`amount`, -`amount`)) AS `balance` 
FROM `payments`
GROUP BY `userid`;
```